# Copying one DOM XML node to another in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

I wrote a simple function to copy contents(including all child nodes) from one node to another of an XML DOM Object.

Surprisingly in the function, the for loop is not iterating for n=1 for some reason i cant figure out, please help, i've been trying to debug this in all possible ways from 4 days.

This function is not iterating for n=1 (i.e. it's iterating for n=0 and n=2 and so on except n=1):

```
function copyNode(fromNode, toNode) {

 for (var n=0; n [lessthan] fromNode.childNodes.length; n++) {
   var fromChild = fromNode.childNodes[n];
   var toChild = toNode.appendChild(fromChild);
   copyNode(fromChild, toChild);
 }
}
```

Full code:

```
<html>
<head>


<script type="text/javascript">

//STANDARD TEXT to XMLDOM OBJECT RETURN FUNCTION
function getXmlDoc(text){
var xmldoc = null;
try //Internet Explorer
{
xmldoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
xmldoc.async="false";
xmldoc.loadXML(text);
return xmldoc;
}
catch(e)
{
try //Firefox, Mozilla, Opera, etc.
{
parser=new DOMParser();
xmldoc=parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");
return xmldoc;
}
catch(e)
{
alert(e.message);
return;
}
}
}
//END OF getXmlDoc

//Function that refuses to work, the 2nd child is always being skipped, i.e n=1 is never running :(, ONLY n=1 is not running
function copyNode(fromNode, toNode) {

 for (var n=0; n [lessthan] fromNode.childNodes.length; n++) {
   var fromChild = fromNode.childNodes[n];
   var toChild = toNode.appendChild(fromChild);
   copyNode(fromChild, toChild);
 }
}

//Function to clear a node's contents
function clearNode(node2)
{
x2=node2.childNodes;
if(x2.length!=0)
{
for(i=0;i [lessthan] x2.length;i++)
{
    node2.removeChild(x2[i]);
}
}
}

//XML1
text="<book>";
text=text+"<title>Everyday Italian</title>";
text=text+"<author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>";
text=text+"<year>2005</year>";
text=text+"</book>";

xmlDoc=getXmlDoc(text);

//XML2
text2="<book>";
text2=text2+"<title><a>1</a><b>2</b><c><ca>3</ca></c></title>";
text2=text2+"<year>2006</year>";
text2=text2+"</book>";

xmlDoc2=getXmlDoc(text2);

x=xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes;
y=xmlDoc2.documentElement.childNodes;
var string = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(y[0]);
alert(string);
var string = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(x[0]);
alert(string);
clearNode(x[0]);
copyNode(y[0],x[0]);
var string = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlDoc);
alert(string);
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you move (not copy) the source nodes to the destination, they are removed from the list of childNodes on the source, and its length decreases.

You should use something like:

```
while (fromNode.firstChild) {
    toNode.appendChild(fromNode.firstChild);
}
```

instead.

Also, you don't need the recursion; when the node is moved, all its children will be moved with it.

Comment: thank you, sir, you saved me from brain-damage. i thought it was copying the node and not moving it because none of the functions explicitly specify the word move/copy. and i was always debugging to check the resultant node and never check what was happening to the source node. ty once again

Answer (score 0):

Your line:

```
copyNode(toChild, fromChild);
```

should be

```
copyNode(fromChild, toChild);
```

When your function comes from recursion your fromChild element is empty...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I would do it (which may or may not be preferred).

```
function copyElementChildren(fromNode,toNode){
    for (var i in fromNode.childNodes) {
        var node = fromNode.childNodes[i].cloneNode(true);
        toNode.appendChild(node);
    };
};
```

This uses cloning to copy it the element. The true in cloneNode(true) tells the browser to copy its attributes and childNodes as well.

Comment: thank you for the answer but i got this error in firefox "
Error: fromNode.childNodes[i].cloneNode is not a function"
i dint explore it further because the above solution worked, please let me know if you want me to debug the code with your solution.

Comment: That's interesting. I confess I didn't test the code since I've never actually needed to clone a node before. I took cloneNode from https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.cloneNode so I'm surprised it didn't work.